# Why does my POST request get a 404 error while GET works fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, web, axios

I'm having issues sending post requests. Whenever I try and send a post request to `localhost:5000/api` it gives me this error "POST `http://localhost:5000/api` 404 (Not Found)" but whenever I do a get request it gives me no errors and works perfectly.

```
const createPost = async () => {
    let res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api", {"id" : 4, "name" : "this was posted by code :)"})
    console.log(res)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api").then(res => {
      setBackendData(res.data)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, [])
```

If you need anymore of my code please tell me.

Comment: Show us your backend code.

Comment: Because the endpoint doesn't support POST?

Comment: Here's most of my backend code, im using express btw.
[link](https://pastebin.com/Q8FQx9PD)

Comment: @8iggy why are you using `router.post()` but `app.get()`? Also, please add your code to your question instead of linking to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend has been written specifically without support for post. If you want, you could read [this w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) article on what different http methods exist. In the modern age, it's all semantic so what api endpoints you choose is up to you (post is generally recommended for security reasons though).

If you want your backend to support post, change your code to use `app.post` instead of `app.get`.